# How to get attr value in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, alert

I am trying to get value of attr " _last_val " from my input  but unable to produce it.

Below is ? i have tried [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59o60g7e/3/)

//below is HTML

```
<form method="post" action="" id="feedback_form">
  <input type="text" value="2014-08-11" class="date" name="add_by_datetime" _last_val="2014-08-14" >
  <input type="button" name="submit_now" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

// below is script

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $("form#feedback_form input[name='submit_now']").on("click",function() { 
      var actualadddate  = $("form#feedback_form input[name='add_by_datetime']").attr('_last_val');
      alert(+actualadddate+'aaaaaaaaa');    
   }); 
});
```

please let me know where i am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You got your answer but don't forget to use the inspector and see the javascript console to see what error has happened. In chrome/Firefox, right click anywhere and "Inspect" then choose the console tab.

Comment: Learn to use `console.log`

Comment: hmm ..actually i am so impatient :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the preceded `+` from alert and try,

```
alert(actualadddate + 'aaaaaaaaa');
```

**[Live working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/59o60g7e/6/)**

Note that, in your example you are using `.date class` to access the attribute if your page has more than 1 element having same class then it will not give you the accurate date. So, be carefull in that case or use `unique id` to get the attribute.

Comment: hey rohan .. you right i am using above input 2 time in my form ... but name="add_by_datetime" and  name="add_by_datetimess" , hence  will use input[name='add_by_datetime'] instead of class  :) thanks for support

Answer (score 4):

Remove `+` operator from beginning. Use:

```
alert(actualadddate+"aaaaaaaaa");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/manantwar/706jdtoj/)**

Answer (score 4):

because of the `+` before actualadddate its converted to a number, that results in NaN (`Not a Number`)

so, remove it

```
alert(actualadddate+'aaaaaaaaa');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59o60g7e/10/

Answer (score 3):

Since, `actualadddate` is not a number, it thows NaN i.e. not a number. Remove `+` from the alert which you used to typecast.

Use this instead,

`alert(actualadddate+"aaaaaaaaa");`

Also, instead of using user defined attributes. Use `data` attribute to store your custom values.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing wrong in your code is the `alert` call.  http://jsfiddle.net/rcnw1op0/